# WatchKit UIPageControl Dot Colour

Tags: ios, uikit, watchkit, uipagecontrol

When I was watching one of the [videos from Apple](http://www.apple.com/watch/films/#film-design) about the Apple Watch and its features I noticed that the page indicator dot colours change depending on the page presented.

They've also got images of the coloured dots within the [Apple Watch Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/WatchHumanInterfaceGuidelines/WatchOSAppAnatomy.html) **App Anatomy** section. Note the coloured title text as well.

[image]

Normally in [WatchKit](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/) I would use the following snippet of code to do this:

```
let features = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
let controllers = [String](count: features.count, repeatedValue: "FeatureInterfaceController")
self.presentControllerWithNames(controllers, contexts: features)
```

Unfortunately as far as I know there isn't a way to access the `currentPageIndicatorTintColor` and `pageIndicatorTintColor` as you normally would as part of `UIKit` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPageControl.html) (scroll down to *Tint Color*).

I wonder if Apple simply just added those colours for the video or whether they're actually going to be available as part of WatchKit in the future?

Perhaps I'm wrong and there is a way to change these dot colours.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As written by an Apple Engineer in the Dev Forums, it's not possible to customize the color of the page control at this time.

Source: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1100695#1100695

Comment: The link doesn't work for me.  Could you please copy & paste what you read, if you can access it?